# "Error initializing Network Connection: Class not found", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I created an android project  in eclipse.

Next I decided to make it cordova app and then added reference to cordova jar and js file.

Next I wrote a plugin to call java class from Javascript.

When I Launch , I get the error "Class not Found".

How do I solve this ? Is there any safe way to add cordova to an already existing android project?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had copied the config.xml from an existing cordova project.

I solved the issue by copying the config.xml from Phonegap download [link](http://phonegap.com/install/) and then adding my single plugin on top of that.